# Synantic Inc fingerprint reader ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, fingerprint-reader

I am using ubuntu 20.04 HP Probook 450 g7 and when I try to add finger print through Settings -> Users-> Authentication & Login -> FingerPrint Login, it says "Could not access any fingerprint reader". My device id is: Bus 001 Device 003: ID 06cb:00df Synaptics, Inc. The device is supported by libfptint. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem here. Did you solve this in the mean time?
The error message I get is: "Failed to claim fingerprint device Synaptics Sensors: Open failed with error: Device 06cb:00df is already open"

Answer (score 1):

On my EliteBook 845 G7 I have the same Synaptics fingerpint reader (06cb:00df see also [linux-hardware profile](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:06cb-00df)). This was fixed by updating the firmware using `fwupdmgr`. However, at the time of writing (2021-02-15) this firmware image is only available in the lvfs-testing repository. So first add `lvfs-testing` (instructions [here](https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/wiki/LVFS-Testing-remote)), and then update your firmware again (instructions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/623929/fprintd-the-driver-encountered-a-protocol-error-with-the-device)). Or in summary:

- `fwupdmgr enable-remote lvfs-testing`
- `fwupdmgr refresh`
- `fwupdmgr update`

Note that I found the solution thanks to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/AMDLaptops/comments/lg0knl/hp_elitebook_835845_g7_linux_compatibility/gmrsqjf?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) Reddit thread.